# Angular ng-select - bindValue don't work and still binds to whole object

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-ngselect

I have a problem with ng-select (I am using newest version and Angular 10).

I am creating a common component called `form-row-select-multiple`, which I will be using in many other components. Here is shortened TS file of this component:

```
  @Input() options: any[] = [];
  @Input() optionKey = 'id'; // in case of options object, specify prop
  @Input() optionKeyText = 'name'; // in case of options object, specify prop to show on option textValue
  @Input() isMultiple = true;
  @Input() selectedValues: any;
  @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  elementId: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (typeof this.selectedValues === 'object' && this.selectedValues !== null && this.selectedValues.length > 0) {
      this.selectedValues = this.selectedValues.map(value => value[this.optionKey]);
    }
  }

  onChange(event: any) {
    this.valueChange.emit(event);
  }

  trackById(item: any) {
    return item.id;
  }
```

And HTML of this component:

```
<ng-select
    [multiple]="isMultiple"
    [id]="elementId"
    [items]="options"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"
    [bindLabel]="optionKeyText"
    [bindValue]="optionKey"
    (add)="onChange($event)"
    [trackByFn]="trackById"
  >
```

As you can see in TS file, I am passing @Input() options from another component, where I am getting data asynchronously from server. My problem is, that despite of using [bindValue]="optionKey" on , it stills bind its value to the whole object (when I log value of event in onChange function, it logs whole object).

BindLabel works fine, so I am not sure why bindValue not. I thought that it might be because of that [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" is also object, so I implemented a logic in ngOnInit, where if selectedValues are objects, I will do a simple array from that. But that did not resolve my problem.

Do you please have any idea, where the problem might be? No errors showing up in the console. Thank you for all ideas.

Comment: Could you please say what is expected? Do you wish to emit arrays of IDs instead of the whole object?

Comment: @MichaelD yes, I want to emit array of IDs, not array of selected objects.

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bindValue` option determines the model to be held by the variable bound to the `ngModel` binding, not the event emitted by the `add` event. So you could instead emit the `ngModel` bound variable.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
}

onChange(event: any) {
  this.valueChange.emit(this.selectedValues);
}
```

Also the `add` event is emitted only when options are added to the list and not everytime that value is changed. For that you need to use `change` event.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aso6o7)

Comment: thank you so much, it works. I've been struggling with this for 2 hours, so really thank you:).

Comment: I've also removed that part with selectedValue in onInit and replaced it with compareWith function.